# Google Drive API Folder Creation and upload files by Service account in Google Drive Failed and generate 404 error after 1 day

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, google-drive-api, tags, directory

Environment: PHP

Working with folders and files: 
I created a folder and 4 sub folders within that folder in my google drive.

Google DRIVE API

1. Create a new console project and automatically enable the Drive API
2. Service account: Create Service account and download the configuration file.

Install the Google Client Library.

```
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0
```

I shared [these folder and 4 sub folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uR1P.png) with service account.

Expected Result: Folders and files should be create in sub Folders.

Actual Result:

```
1 day it works properly but in next day 404 error updated in error log.
{ "error": {"errors": [{ "domain": "global","reason": "notFound","message": "File not found: .","locationType": "parameter","location": "fileId"} ],"code": 404, "message": "File not found: ." } }
```

**MY Code:**

```
//======Send To Google Drive======//
function send_google_drive($id,$fileno,$filename1,$filename2){
            global $wpdb;
            require(ABSPATH.'/wp-content/themes/enemat/googledrives/vendor/autoload.php');
            $client = getClient();
            $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
            $folderslink = "";
            $docusignorgs = "";
            $contractdrivelink = "";
            $parentfolders = get_option("parentfolders");
            $crmfolders = get_option("crmfolders");
            try{
            //===Root Folder's Sub Folder======//
            $results = $service->files->listFiles();
            $parents = "";
            foreach ($results->getFiles() as $item) {
                if ($item['name'] == $parentfolders) {
                        $parents = $item['id'];
                        break;
                }
            }

             $optParams = array(
                'pageSize' => 10,
                'fields' => "nextPageToken, files(contentHints/thumbnail,fileExtension,iconLink,id,name,size,thumbnailLink,webContentLink,webViewLink,mimeType,parents)",
                'q' => "'".$parents."' in parents"
            );
           $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
           $parentsarray = array();
           foreach ($results->getFiles() as $item) {
                $parentsarray[$item['name']] = $item->getId();        
           }
           $parentid = $parentsarray[$crmfolders];
          //===Root Folder's Sub Folder======//
          //===Sub Folder's Folders======//
            $optParams1 = array(
                'pageSize' => 10,
                'fields' => "nextPageToken, files(contentHints/thumbnail,fileExtension,iconLink,id,name,size,thumbnailLink,webContentLink,webViewLink,mimeType,parents)",
                'q' => "'".$parentid."' in parents"
            );
            $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams1);
           //===Sub Folder's Folders======//    
          //==========CREATE FOLDER====//
            $childid = "";
            foreach ($results->getFiles() as $item) {
                if ($item['name'] == $fileno) {
                    $childid = $item['id'];
                        break;
                    }
            }
            if(empty($childid)){
                    $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
                                        'name' => $fileno,
                                        'parents'=>array($parentid),
                                        'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'));
                                        $file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
                                        'fields' => 'id'));
                $folderId = $file->id;
            }else{
                $folderId = $childid;
            }
            $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
            $newPermission->setType('anyone');
            $newPermission->setRole('reader');
            $service->permissions->create($folderId, $newPermission);
            //==========CREATE FOLDER====//     
            if(!empty($filename1)){
                try{
                    $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
                                'name' => "OFFRE DE PRIME - ".$fileno."",
                                'parents' => array($folderId)
                            ));
                            $content = file_get_contents($filename1);
                            $files = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
                                    'data' => $content,
                                    'uploadType' => 'resumable',
                                    'fields' => 'id')); 
                    $fileids = $files->id; 
                    $docusignorgs = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=".$fileids."";
                    $folderslink = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/".$folderId."";
                    @unlink(ABSPATH."wp-content/themes/enemat/pdfs/".basename($filename1));
                    $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
                    $newPermission->setType('anyone');
                    $newPermission->setRole('reader');
                    $service->permissions->create($fileids, $newPermission);
                }catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
                   $file_save = false;
                   file_put_contents(ABSPATH."wp-content/themes/enemat/ajax_scripts/error_logs.txt",$e->getMessage(),FILE_APPEND);
                }catch (Google_IOException $e) {
                  $file_save = false;
                  file_put_contents(ABSPATH."wp-content/themes/enemat/ajax_scripts/error_logs.txt",$e->getMessage(),FILE_APPEND);
                } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
                  $file_save = false;
                  file_put_contents(ABSPATH."wp-content/themes/enemat/ajax_scripts/error_logs.txt",$e->getMessage(),FILE_APPEND);
                }catch (Exception $e) {
                    $file_save = false;
                    file_put_contents(ABSPATH."wp-content/themes/enemat/ajax_scripts/error_logs.txt",$e->getMessage(),FILE_APPEND);
                }
            }

            if(!empty($filename2)){
                try{
                $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
                                'name' => "contrat projet - ".$fileno."",
                                'parents' => array($folderId)
                            ));
                $content = file_get_contents($filename2);
                $files = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
                                    'data' => $content,
                                    'uploadType' => 'resumable',
                                    'fields' => 'id')); 
                $fileids1 = $files->id; 
                $contractdrivelink = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=".$fileids1."";
                $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
                $newPermission->setType('anyone');
                $newPermission->setRole('reader');
                $service->permissions->create($fileids1, $newPermission);
                @unlink(ABSPATH."wp-content/themes/enemat/pdfs/".basename($filename2));
                }catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
                   $file_save = false;
                   file_put_contents(ABSPATH."wp-content/themes/enemat/ajax_scripts/error_logs.txt",$e->getMessage(),FILE_APPEND);
                }catch (Google_IOException $e) {
                  $file_save = false;
                  file_put_contents(ABSPATH."wp-content/themes/enemat/ajax_scripts/error_logs.txt",$e->getMessage(),FILE_APPEND);
                } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
                  $file_save = false;
                  file_put_contents(ABSPATH."wp-content/themes/enemat/ajax_scripts/error_logs.txt",$e->getMessage(),FILE_APPEND);
                }catch (Exception $e) {
                    $file_save = false;
                    file_put_contents(ABSPATH."wp-content/themes/enemat/ajax_scripts/error_logs.txt",$e->getMessage(),FILE_APPEND);
                }
            }
            $SQLUPDATE = "UPDATE wp_clientinfo SET docusignorgs='".$docusignorgs."',folderid='".$folderslink."',contractdrivelink='".$contractdrivelink."' WHERE id='".$id."'";
            $wpdb->query($SQLUPDATE);
            }catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
                   $file_save = false;
                   file_put_contents(ABSPATH."wp-content/themes/enemat/ajax_scripts/error_logs.txt",$e->getMessage(),FILE_APPEND);
            }catch (Google_IOException $e) {
                  $file_save = false;
                  file_put_contents(ABSPATH."wp-content/themes/enemat/ajax_scripts/error_logs.txt",$e->getMessage(),FILE_APPEND);
            } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
                  $file_save = false;
                  file_put_contents(ABSPATH."wp-content/themes/enemat/ajax_scripts/error_logs.txt",$e->getMessage(),FILE_APPEND);
            }catch (Exception $e) {
                    $file_save = false;
                    file_put_contents(ABSPATH."wp-content/themes/enemat/ajax_scripts/error_logs.txt",$e->getMessage(),FILE_APPEND);
            }
        }
//======Send To Google Drive======//
```

Comment: Hello pinoyyid, I have deleted other posts , i hope you have all info and that you will be able to help :)

Comment: I have post a job on up work if a specialist want to work on it I will be very happy pinoyyid?or someone else? thanks https://www.upwork.com/jobs/~011b3208e8326acbb4